# obvious results

Tags: muscle-gain

I am a person who does workouts.My problem is that i am trying hard to obtain obvious muscles.In workout it seemed my muscles but when i stop after 2hours there are not seemed obvious. Additionaly,I did blood test my sugar level was 94 to 108 ml/gr and my cholisterol 204 from 200.Now,there are pass 3-4 weeks i havent eat sugar not a single sweet and i am not eating much things has to do with cholisterol. I start eating more healthier.Before workout i eat banana after i eat some of the depeneds on my will  eggs or milk with quaker/ omega-3/green apple/ greek yogurt/ honey/chicken/meat/other food or vegetables salats.I am 65kg i have little obvious muscles but nothing the truth for the distance i am workout.Guys how will i see quaranteen results. Should i do from morning until night workout to change my food. What should i add ..my workouts are good . all say its my metabolism or the foods..

Comment: Unfortunately, it's really hard to understand what you are really asking. If you can clarify if you are asking about your nutrition, or how to enhance the workouts, please see if you can make it clearer and then nominate the question for reopening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 1/2 understand what you're saying but to simply put on size --  From your post it sounds like your lifting for 2 hours.  WAY too long.

Here's a simple tip if you're trying to put on muscle

Do eccentric exercises -- this is when growth occurs.

For example here's a great exercise for biceps -- bring an adjustable bench over to the pull-up bar (your using this to kick yourself back to the top after you reach the bottom)

- Kick off the bench or jump up and Start with your chin at the top of the bar
- Resist your body weight from pulling you down (but it will slowly)
- Right before you get to the ground kick off the bench to go back to the starting position and repeat.
- Do this 5 times hold as long as you can -- rest 1:30 - 2 min between sets

Essentially you're attempting to curl your body weight.  So you're maximally contracting as your being lower to the floor by gravity.